# Pandas max value in column and subtract

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe like:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3],
               'B':[3,2,20,1,6,2,3,22,1]})
```

I would like to find the 'max' value in column 'B' then subtract this max value from all the values in column 'B' and create a new column 'C' with the new result. Max is 22 for bottom df.

```
   A  B  C
2  1  3  -19
1  1  2  -20
0  1  20 -2
3  2  1  -21
5  2  6  -16
4  2  2  -20
8  3  3  -19
7  3  22  0
6  3  1  -21
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can assign your new column with the result of subtracting column 'B' with [`max`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.max.html) of column 'B':

```
In [25]:
df['C'] = df['B'] - df['B'].max()
df

Out[25]:
   A   B   C
0  1   3 -19
1  1   2 -20
2  1  20  -2
3  2   1 -21
4  2   6 -16
5  2   2 -20
6  3   3 -19
7  3  22   0
8  3   1 -21
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`sub`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.sub.html) for substracting [`max`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.max.html) value of column `B`:

```
df['C'] = df['B'].sub(df['B'].max())
print (df)

   A   B   C
0  1   3 -19
1  1   2 -20
2  1  20  -2
3  2   1 -21
4  2   6 -16
5  2   2 -20
6  3   3 -19
7  3  22   0
8  3   1 -21
```

Another solution with [`assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html):

```
df = df.assign(C=df['B'].sub(df['B'].max()))
print (df)
   A   B   C
0  1   3 -19
1  1   2 -20
2  1  20  -2
3  2   1 -21
4  2   6 -16
5  2   2 -20
6  3   3 -19
7  3  22   0
8  3   1 -21
```